# Perl Daemon Not Working with Sleep()

Tags: perl, daemon

I wrote a simple test daemon using [Proc::Daemon](http://search.cpan.org/~deti/Proc-Daemon-0.14/lib/Proc/Daemon.pod) .  Here is the daemon:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 use Proc::Daemon;

 $daemon = Proc::Daemon->new(
        work_dir     => '/scripts/',
        child_STDOUT => '/scripts/child.log',
        child_STDERR => '+>>debugchild.txt',
        pid_file     => 'pid.txt',
        exec_command => 'perl /scripts/test.pl'
    );


foreach(@ARGV)
{
if ( /install/i )
{
    $Kid_1_PID = $daemon->Init;
}
elsif (/remove/i)
{
    $stopped = $daemon->Kill_Daemon();
}
}
```

And here is test that it executes:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

while (1) {

print "test\n";
sleep(1);
}
```

The while loop works fine with just the print statement, but when I add sleep(); the log is empty.  Why would this be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl will not automatically flush the buffer so your write to the file will only happen after quite a while. When you don't have the sleep your buffer will be almost automatically flushing due to the volume of data being written.

Try this:

```
$| = 1;
while (1) {
    print "test\n";
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what $| = 1 does?

Comment: It tells Perl to flush the buffer after each write rather than waiting until there are enough bytes in the buffer to send it to a file.

Answer (score 4):

Output buffering and not enough patience? With a `sleep(1)` in the loop, it could take a while for enough data to accumulate and be flushed to the log file.

Put a [`$|=1;`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#%24OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH) statement at the top of your script.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use:

*to flush the print on console*:

```
select()->flush();
```

*to flush in to the file with the fileHandle $FH*

```
$FH->autoflush;
```